# How to Highlight Active Tab Using Navigation Routes in Twitter Bootstrap MVC4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-routing

my question is how to highlight the active tab using the route-based menu system with Twitter Bootstrap for MVC4. If a parent tab contains child routes, when the child route is selected, the corresponding parent tab should be highlighted. Please consider the example code below and thank you for your help.

Below is an example from my RouteConfig:

```
    routes.MapNavigationRoute<DashController>("Parent 1", c => c.Index(), "", true);

    routes.MapNavigationRoute<MainController>("Parent 2", c => c.Index())
                    .AddChildRoute<MainController>("Child 1", c => c.do_something(), "", true)
                    .AddChildRoute<MainController>("Child 2", c => c.do_something_else(), "", true)
;
```

Below is an example from my _Layout shared view:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav"> 
                            @Html.Navigation()
                        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation/V2#navs) there is a way to set links active inside the Nav by using extension methods: `.SetLinksActiveByController()` or `.SetLinksActiveByControllerAndAction()`